# Using Raspberry Pi to flash its own SD card

Tags: sd-card, software-development, buildroot

I'm developing a Buildroot OS for the Raspberry Pi, and my workflow requires very frequent re-flashing of the SD card to test new iterations. The process of removing the SD card from the Pi, flashing it on a Windows PC and then re-inserting it takes a lot of time.
I would like to write a script that uses the currently running OS on the Rpi (accessed over SSH) to

1. Download the new SD image
2. Flash it to the SD, overwriting all existing OS files
3. Reboot into the new OS

Step 2 is where I'm stuck. Is it possible for an operating system to overwrite itself?

Comment: You may consider to use net booting for development.

Comment: This is a comment because I don't know if it would work, but can you have two partitions on the SD card, write to the second partition and then boot from that new partition next time?  As you iterate through changes, you're just booting from one partition or the other?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, that's possible, except you would not want to write a (normative) Pi OS image to the other partition -- you'd want to write the contents of the root filesystem, which you can extract from the image.  That requires a bit of manual (or scriptable) tinkering.   Then you'd want to update the boot partition, and set `root=` in `cmdline.txt`.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a usb sd card reader/writer.

Answer (score 11):

To overwrite itself, your operating system must run fully in RAM and **neither read nor write** from SD card after booting. [piCore/TinyCore](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/ports.html) is probably one of the few Linux OS which can do that.

Comment: Is is necessary that the OS *never* read/write to SD, or merely that is doesn't require the SD during the dd operation?

Comment: @JeremiahRose If anything else writes to a part of the SD card `dd` is done with, it's gonna screw up the image.

Comment: @JeremiahRose Strictly speaking, as long as you can _completely certainly guarantee_ that _absolutely no modification of the SD card_ will happen while `dd` is running, then it's fine if it modifies the SD card outside of that. Practically speaking, just go with an OS that never modifies the SD card; it'll be simpler to reason about.

Comment: "while dd is running" -- not just while it's running, after it's finished. The OS is likely to cache various filesystem metadata, such as _where files live on the SD card_. If, after dd is done running, it decides to write to one of these files (which are no longer where the OS thinks they are), it'll overwrite some other arbitrary data instead.

Comment: An OS running purely in RAM is a straightforward and general purpose solution, but in some way I'm a bit disappointed if there doesn't exist a program that would just lock itself and the image file to memory, prevent other processes from running (setting itself to run with real-time scheduling or something) and then write the image and reboot the system.

Comment: @ilkkachu, the problem with that is many processes like to write an update of some sort to themselves when they shut down. Preventing that may cause RTEs, causing unexpected other errors. Even OSs like to do this. Preventing the OS from an update on shutdown by a program running on the OS isn't likely to work, since the program will be shutdown prior to the OS, which would then have access to the card, defeating the program unintentionally.

Comment: Based on your comments I'm trying to think of a way to improve my answer so that it 1. halts the system immediately after dd (without shutdown) and 2. locks the SD from being written to by any other process (just changing permissions on the /dev/mmcblk0 should do it?)

Comment: @JeremiahRose Maybe adding an overlayfs layer backed by a ramfs over the SD card before running `dd` and then doing an "emergency" reboot (a bit like typing [Alt-SysRq-U and then Alt-SysRq-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key))? Just speculating, not sure this could be done on-the-fly.

Comment: @computercarguy, I would say it's a rare program that insists on writing updates when shutting down (except probably everything using sqlite or such, but e.g. the usual command line utilities don't fall into that). In any case, what I'm talking about would be a program built for that very purpose, and would just ask for a hard and immediate reboot, not a userspace shutdown.

Comment: @ilkkachu, if it has a logging system anything like Windows, it'll want to write a log saying why the shutdown happened. If that's not handled correctly by the current disk layout, you could accidentally overwrite part of the the system files, or simply be a benign entry in the middle of what should be whitespace. There could also be an automatic update for the running OS that starts after you reimage, causing the same type of issue. The point is that, as a user, you don't have as much control as you think you do.

Comment: @computercarguy, yes, I had the hidden assumption or a Linux system (I do believe it's what is rather commonly used on Raspberries and other similar devices too). Of course not everyone runs Linux, and stuff like that _is_ dependant on the OS, but so is running the OS from RAM.

Comment: @computercarguy, but as for automatic updates and such, do note that I did say _"prevent other processes from running"_.

Comment: @ilkkachu "prevent other processes from running", that's not usually as easy as it sounds. What happens when a process required to run the wipe & reimage also requires another process which requires another process (in ad infinitum) that eventually wants to write something to the drive? That's all too common and often difficult to get around or efficiently rewrite when the process requirements change on the OS. It's something to think about, not a guarantee it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out elsewhere, `dd`-ing over a running OS is never a good idea. An alternative (and the usual way you'd develop embedded systems) is to have your OS image served from a network drive and the target board perform a network boot. This speeds up the initial development and you only need to write out the SD cards as you get closer to completion and need to test on actual hardware.

There's a write up on setting the PI3B and PI3B+ to boot from a server on the Foundation pages: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/net_tutorial.md

Comment: In my case, dd-ing over the running OS has caused absolutely no problems at all

Comment: Beware this is a bit like saying you drive drunk often and have no problems at all, or take the stairs in the dark all the time and have no problems at all, etc.  It is a bit different than that those things, though, in that when it goes wrong you won't have any opportunity to react to it.   OTOH, you're not going to get injured or killed, so "it works until it doesn't" maybe fine with your workflow.

Comment: This is similar to the technique people use to run utilities like nwipe for securely erasing an entire hard disk: https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe/

Answer (score 3):

## Use an SD card large enough to hold multiple partitions

The SD card should hold a boot partition (0) and three OS partitions (1-3).

The boot loader on the boot partition would examine the partition labels to determine what to load.  Suppose the labels are:

> 0: BOOT
>   1: OS-0004!
>   2: OS-0002
>   3: OS-0003

The loader knows to load the OS from partition 1, as it's the last label when they're sorted.  And the first OS label is partition 2, to which it writes the update

> 2: OS-0005_

This is now the last label, but the underscore flag tells the loader it's the first attempt to boot from it.  It changes the label to indicate it's doing a test boot right before it chains to it:

> 2: OS-0005?
>   If the OS successfully boots and passes its own sanity checks, it updates the label one more time, as well as the label of the previous OS partition:
>   1: OS-0004
>   2: OS-0005!

If it fails, the next time it tries to boot, it will see the ? flag and revert to load from partition 1, whereupon the update will start over.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting outline, but do you have any specifics how to do this?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I know that boot loaders are capable of this sort of thing.  The Google Chromebook system is similar, in that it has a boot partition, at least two OS partitions, and a user-space partition, so that updates are always applied to the OS partition the system did _not_ boot from.

Answer (score 2):

## Use with caution

This works for me because I am using a **read-only root filesystem** with a custom Buildroot OS. This script hasn't been tested on Raspbian yet, but will probably work.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Copying image to RPi..."
sshpass -p PASSWORD scp /PATH/TO/SDCARD.img USER@RPI:/tmp/sdcard.img
echo "Flashing image to /dev/mmvblk0 on RPi..."
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh USER@RPI 'nice -20 sudo sh -c "sync && dd if=/tmp/sdcard.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 conv=fdatasync && reboot -f"'
```

This should be run on the host computer (**not** the RPi) and does the following:

1. Copies the SD image to the RPi via scp
2. Logs into the RPi via ssh
3. Syncs all pending OS write operations to SD card
4. Sets priority to -20 to prevent other processes from running
5. Flashes the image to the SD card followed by a fdatasync
6. Performs a hard reset

**Limitations:**

- If data is written to the SD card by another process while the script is running, the SD may become corrupted. In a few days of active use, I haven't encountered this yet - but I am not using Raspbian.
- Make sure you only use this script for development/testing, not for upgrading your OS or any other data-sensitive applications.
- Could use some improvements to further prevent other processes from accessing the SD card - suggestions welcome.

**To use:**

1. Copy the above script into a `flash.sh` file on your host PC
2. Fill in your settings for password, username, SD image etc
3. Make it executable with `chmod a+x flash.sh`
4. Install `sshpass` and `ssh` on host: `sudo apt install sshpass openssh`
5. Make sure ssh login is working on the RPi
6. Run `./flash.sh`

Comment: There are cases where the image is heavier than the memory of the raspy, what could we do in those cases?

Comment: Yeah, those cases sound impossible to work around

Answer (score 2):

All your requirements are already available in my Nard SDK distro. It runs from RAM and there are ready made scripts for remote image upgrades.
http://www.nard.se/

Comment: Nice project! I've got a question: Most of the [Examples](http://www.nard.se/examples.html) listed seem like things that are also being done with RPi/Raspbian, so I'm not clear on the advantages of your (Nard) system. Edit yr answer to elaborate?

Comment: @Seamus Where Nard shines is for large volume products. Say for example you build some kind of machine with an embedded Pi. The machine is then sold in +100 copies. The absence of such user products in the website is political. Manufacturers never agrees to becoming a reference. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here a rough approach:

1. Replace /sbin/init with upgrade tool.
2. Tell init to re-exec itself.
3. Kill all other remaining processes (for example with `kill -9 -1`)
4. Use `pivot_root` and `chroot` to replace the root filesystem.
5. If necessary `exec` the next stage to drop references the old root.
6. Recursively unmount the old root.
7. Write the new image.
8. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about something similar for testing development/deployment from a fresh install of Raspbian. My current thinking is a dual sd-card, usb-drive set up. So on each boot, the pi first boots into the sd-card, flashes a fresh install to the usb drive, and then chroots into the usb-drive to start the os.

Though as this is only text, i've only thought about it conceptually while manually flashing sd card's with other devices. So I guess I should start looking into implementation..